# css problems and solution to adding to a div

Tags: asp.net, html, css, stylesheet

I have a problem im trying to solve with css its best I show you with an image:

[image]

My css:

```
div#test {
width:90%; 
z-index:1; 
padding:27.5px; 
border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
color:#ffffff;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Im trying to get it to wrap in all broswer types?

The other problem im wondering is if you look at the first image and a cropted image below I would also like to try add an X plus comment and img (hyperlinks) to each div like so:

[image]

No sure if thats possible via css?

Comment: Which browsers does it fail in? Also, could you include your HTML code?

Comment: You first issue i believe can be solved by adding a "position: relative" to your div#test. The other question's answer depends on where you get your data from. It would personally suggest you use asp:repeater to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, this should do the trick:

```
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: pre-line;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The order of those is important, for CSS2/CSS2.1/CSS3 progressive enhancement.

For the second issue, it's possible, sure, but semantically it depends what the image is of. If it's not content-related, then use `background-image: url('somepath/someimage.png');`. Otherwise use an `img` tag in the HTML.

Comment: Id like to set the content of the img in the code behind in asp, Id also like to shrink the image if at all possible? If you could ammend an answer for both parts I will give the correct answer to you.

Comment: also what about the position of the image within the div? and the commenst and x hyperlinks?

Comment: by that I mean setting the img to <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /> can css set asp imgs?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, try adding `word-wrap: break-word;`.

For your second question, you could try using the CSS `:after` pseudo selector (IE 8+ only) but I think you'd be much better off doing this with JavaScript (i.e. after the DOM loads, iterate over each row and create/append some new tags) - jQuery could make this quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

First part of your question sounds like you need to use CSS `word-wrap`:

```
#test {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap for more info.

Also see http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap for browser support details (it's pretty much universally supported, so no problems there).

For the second part of the question, you should set the container `<div>` to `position:relative;`. Then you can use `position:absolute;` for the elements within it that you want to be in fixed positions, and position them with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` as applicable.